# How can I install imagick in current enabled PHP version?

Tags: php, apache, debian, imagick

I have multiple PHP version installed (7.0, 7.1 and 7.3). I have enabled PHP 7.0 (I need to keep this version for various reasons). When I try to install imagick (via sudo apt-get install php-imagick) the libraries are copied/installed only for PHP 7.3, despite I'm  using 7.0 as confirmed by php -v and phpinfo file.

Am I missing any Apache setting? Why it doesn't consider the current 7.0 enabled module as default php version while installing new php libraries?

OS: Debian 10
WS: Apache/2.4.38

I've tried to edit php.ini, enable extensions, usual basic procedure... but  imagick.so is compiled for php 7.3 only. There's no trace of them in the extension folder of PHP 7.0 and it's not possible to load it.

**UPDATE #1**

Checking with **sudo update-alternatives --config php** 

I see this table (see image) - I don't know how to change priority or automode. It looks like PHP 7.3 keep the top priority.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkXux.png)

**UPDATE #2**

*Tried this, no results.*

*PHP 7.0 set as default*
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.0
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.0

*Reinstall imagick*
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php-imagick --reinstall

*(no error, but it keeps installing them for PHP 7.3)*

*php -m show no modules, because they are in the extension folder of php 7.3*

Comment: How did you install each version of PHP?

Comment: Usually `apt` favors installing the latest version available, I *don't think* it takes into account `alternatives`. If you are using external repos, they could have higher priority. Try installing `php7.0-imagick`

Comment: @Jonnix via ppa repo.

Comment: All of them? Then they are probably versioned appropriately in the repos. `apt search php imagick` and find the appropriate package to install for each version.

Comment: @Jonnix Yes, all of them. I've updated my question.

Comment: Okay, and what of the rest of my comment?

Comment: @Jonnix sorry, I can't find any from the search.

Comment: If `php7.0-imagick` doesn't produce any result it's probably a leftover from stretch. `apt show` to find the repo it came from. Sury seems to carry php7.0 for debian 10.

Comment: @msg Package 'php7.0-imagick' has no installation candidate

Comment: Try [sury](https://deb.sury.org/) packages seem to be there: [imagick](https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php-imagick/), [php](https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.0/)

Comment: @msg Thanks. It would be great if you can be more detailed in how to proceed with these packages.

Comment: @MineralProbe [Add the repository](https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt) to your `sources.list` and install as you would any other packages. Since 7.0 is not available in buster it'll try to install/update from the new repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 10 uses PHP 7.3 as its "standard" PHP version, so all of its PHP extension packages -- including `php-imagick` -- will contain extensions which target PHP 7.3.

If you have somehow installed PHP 7.0 (which you should not do, as it reached end-of-life in January 2019 and no longer receives security updates), you will need to obtain extensions for it through some other channel.

Comment: Thanks for clarify this aspect. I didn't know that... I was on Debian 9 before, upgraded to Debian 10. That's why I have a PHP 7.0 in it.

Comment: Unfortunately with PHP 7.3 mysqli_real_connect() won't connect to my DB server anymore... But this is another question.

Comment: Then fix that problem! Staying on an obsolete version of PHP isn't a viable long-term solution.